# How to open a new page with data url image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm working with [literallyCanvas](http://literallycanvas.com/examples/export.html) which is the export button will open a new page with data url of the image edited. But I need to change the way it open a new page from an image to a page with var.

This is the original code from source which is open a new page with image:

```
    $("#open-image").click(function() {
      window.open(lc.getImage({
         rect: {x: 0, y: 0, width: 1200, height: 800},
        scale: 1
      }).toDataURL());
    });
```

So, I tried to change the structure with page name in it, and I've got:

```
     $("#open-image").click(function() {
      window.open('preview.php?img='+lc.getImage({rect: {x: 0, y: 0, width: 1200, height: 800},scale: 1})).toDataURL();
    });
```

But it makes my browser frozen. I can't do anything but force it to close and open it again. I really want this button **#open-image** to open a new page like `preview.php?img=apaosidfjskf(123asdfpoa$sldkjfwepfaoASfweas`. But it gives me this instead `preview.php?img=[object HTMLCanvasElement]`

Please suggest me if there's anything I'm done wrong or enlighten me to the solution.

Comment: If you want to display the DataURL as image in a browser, you do not need any PHP for that, just open a new window with the DataURL in it.

Comment: 1. I need PHP to pass the image data along the url.
2. I need to change the action after a button is clicked from just an image into a url with data.

Comment: I'm not sure, but may be the DataURL is too long for URL. Try to use an HTML form with the `POST` method. Just put the DataURL to some hidden `img` input from JS and submit it to PHP

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo

## Code With Typo Corrected

```
$("#open-image").click(function() {
  window.open('preview.php?img=' + lc.getImage({
    rect: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 1200, height: 800 },
    scale: 1
  }).toDataURL()); // This line has been corrected
});
```

That should fix the `preview.php?img=[object HTMLCanvasElement]` problem

Comment: Hm seemed to work for me...
Although having the URI in the URL does cause a `414 Request-URI Too Large` Error